# tcolorbox: TikZ picture option of "tikz lower"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tcblisting

Package `tcolorbox` has defined a style called "tikz lower". The package manual introduces it as follows:

> /tcb/tikz lower=options
>
> This style adds a centered tikzpicture environment to the start and
>   end of the lower part. The options may be given as TikZ picture
>   options.

However, I quite don't understand what it means by saying "TikZ picture options". Here's my attempt to change the scale of two axes (normally I would do `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=10pt,y=20pt]`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newtcblisting{displaytikz}{
    tikz lower,
    % tikz lower={x=10pt,y=20pt},
    listing side text,
    bicolor,colback=blue!30!white,colbacklower=white,
    colframe=black,righthand width=3cm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaytikz}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw (0,0.5) -- (2,0);
\end{displaytikz}

\end{document}
```

I replace the first line in my `\newtcblisting` definition by the commented second line, then I get an error:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/y', to which you
>   passed '20pt]', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled
>   it. \begin{displaytikz}

FYI, I also check the `tcolorbox.sty`, the relevant line is:

```
...
tikz lower/.style={
    before lower=\centering\tcb@shield@externalize\begin{tikzpicture}[#1],
    after lower=\end{tikzpicture}
}, ...
```

I think I must have mistaken something. If `tikz lower` is not for this, then how can I convey arguments to the TikZ environment? Any ideas?

Comment: See https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/40 for a patch which sould solve the problem.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thanks. I've added an answer below to give an example of using TikZ picture options. Hope it can help other users.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @ThomasF.Sturm (the developer of tcolorbox package) and @Ignasi (the answerer above, who reported the issue), here's a ME that passes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Patch start
\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  tikz upper/.style={before upper=\centering\tcb@shield@externalize\begin{tikzpicture}[{#1}],after upper=\end{tikzpicture}},%
  tikz lower/.style={before lower=\centering\tcb@shield@externalize\begin{tikzpicture}[{#1}],after lower=\end{tikzpicture}},%
}
\makeatother

\NewTCBListing{displaytikz}{ O{} }{
    tikz lower={#1},
    listing side text,
    bicolor,colback=blue!30!white,colbacklower=white,
    colframe=black,righthand width=3cm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaytikz}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw (0,0.5) -- (2,0);
\end{displaytikz}

\begin{displaytikz}[x=10pt, y=20pt, red, line width=2pt]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw (0,0.5) -- (2,0);
\end{displaytikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the problem, but this exists not only with `x` and `y` options but with every second option you can include in `tikz lower`. I don't know how to solve it.

As a workaround you can define a `TikZ` style and use it as option for `tikz lower`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    mystyle/.style={x=10pt, y=20pt, red, line width=2pt}}

\newtcblisting{displaytikz}{
    tikz lower={mystyle},
    listing side text,
    bicolor,colback=blue!30!white,colbacklower=white,
    colframe=black,righthand width=3cm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaytikz}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw (0,0.5) -- (2,0);
\end{displaytikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly, no option works. It's weird that the manual says something in that way. Thank you for your brilliant trick and I think your answer is probably what the package expects users to do.

Comment: @wklchris I've reported this issue on `tcolorbox` development place.

Comment: Maybe, you would like to modify your answer with the patch? Thank you for reporting this issue.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm (I'm the questioner) Thank you for your quick response to the issue. Though the answerer has not gone online, I've tested the patch and it works well. Issue here: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/40